# Assigning the value of a tensor by its name

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm grabbing a tensor inside a TensorFlow graph using the following code:

```
names = [var.name for var in self.graph.get_collection('trainable_variables')]
tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name(names[0])
sess.run(tensor)
```

How can I set the value of the `tensor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most TensorFlow tensors (`tf.Tensor` objects) are *immutable*, so you cannot simply assign a value to them. However, if you created the tensor as a [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable), you can assign a value to it by calling [`Variable.assign()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.assign).

The code you have unnecessarily converts a `tf.Variable` object (from the list of `tf.trainable_variables()`) into a string name. Instead, you can do the following:

```
# Get the 0th trainable variable.
var = tf.trainable_variables()[0]

# Create an op to assign a new value.
assign_op = var.assign([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])

# Actually run the assignment.
sess.run(assign_op)
```

---

**However**, according to your comment, you have multiple graphs (i.e. `self.graph` and `graph` are different), so the general solution I wrote above won't work. In this case, you have two options:

1. Get the variable by name in the other graph (**N.B.** this will only work if `graph_2.get_collection('trainable_variables')` has been populated; it won't work if you used `tf.import_graph_def()` to build the graph):

   ```
   var_name = graph_1.get_collection('trainable_variables')[0].name

   var_in_g2 = [v for v in graph_2.get_collection('trainable_variables')
                if v.name == var_name][0]

   assign_op = var_in_g2.assign([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
   sess.run(assign_op)
   ```
2. Get the tensor by name in the other graph, and use `tf.assign()`:

   ```
   var_name = graph_1.get_collection('trainable_variables')[0].name

   var_in_g2 = graph_2.get_tensor_by_name(var_name)

   assign_op = tf.assign(var_in_g2, [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
   sess.run(assign_op)
   ```

Comment: thanks for the info. the problem is that I have multiple graphs and `tf.trainable_variables()` is empty. is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure if `self.graph` and `graph` being different was a typo. I updated the answer to cover your case.